# Auto Generate Post Title from 2 Custom Fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, title

I would like to generate the post title from 2 custom fields, 'job', which is a taxonomy, plus 'date' which is a date picker, not the date of the post. This is for a custom post type called 'job-updates'.

I would also like to hide the title field in the editor.

With help from the ACF community, I have the following code which I have added to "Code Snippets" but it doesn't seem to work. Thoughts?

```
// run function after acf updates fields
add_action('acf/update_post', 20);
function title_from_fields($post_id) {
  // check for your post type
  if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'job-updates') {
    return;
  }
  // get the post
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  // get the taxonomy field
  $terms = get_field('job', $post_id);
  // taxonomy fields return an array, use the first term
  $term = $terms[0];
  // get date field
  $date = get_field('date', $post_id);
  // set post title/slug
  $title = $term->name.' '.$date;
  $post->post_title = $title;
  $post->post_name = sanitize_title($title);
  // remove this filter to prevent infinite loop
  remove_filter('acf/update_post', 20);
  // update the post
  wp_update_post($post);
  // re-add this filter
  add_action('acf/update_post', 20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wordpress `save_post` action to update the `title` using the custom fields as you like. Here is the simple example I have used myself -

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_post_type_title' );
function custom_post_type_title ( $post_id ) {
  global $wpdb;
  if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'job-updates') {
    $terms = get_field('job', $post_id);
    // taxonomy fields return an array, use the first term
    $term = $terms[0];
    // get date field
    $date = get_field('date', $post_id);
    // set post title/slug
    $title = $term->name.' '.$date;
    $where = array( 'ID' => $post_id );
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_title' => $title ), $where );
  }
}
```